# Aligning a JS object to the middle of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently started playing around with js, and specifically - with [this](https://g6.antv.vision/en) graphing library.

I ran some of their example code, and I got somewhat of a noob HTML / js question.

this is their example code:

When I run this code, the graph appears on the left of the div.

I wanted to know how I can align this object to the mid of the div.

I don't really know if this is a "HTML / CSS" task - or rather a "js task" which means I should obtain this behaviour via the object API (tbh, I tried looking into the API and I saw no alignment options).

Sorry if this is a really noobie question, I tried solving it, but I had no success.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Tutorial Demo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="mountNode"></div>
        <script src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/antv/pkg/_antv.g6-3.7.1/dist/g6.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          const graph = new G6.Graph({
            container: 'mountNode',
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            // Default properties for all the nodes
            defaultNode: {
              labelCfg: {
                style: {
                  fill: '#fff',
                },
              },
            },
            // Default properties for all the edges
            defaultEdge: {
              labelCfg: {
                autoRotate: true,
              },
            },
            // The node styles in different states
            nodeStateStyles: {
              // The node style when the state 'hover' is true
              hover: {
                fill: 'lightsteelblue',
              },
              // The node style when the state 'click' is true
              click: {
                stroke: '#000',
                lineWidth: 3,
              },
            },
            // The edge styles in different states
            edgeStateStyles: {
              // The edge style when the state 'click' is true
              click: {
                stroke: 'steelblue',
              },
            },
            // Layout
            layout: {
              type: 'force',
              linkDistance: 100,
              preventOverlap: true,
              nodeStrength: -30,
              edgeStrength: 0.1,
            },
            // Built-in Behaviors
            modes: {
              default: ['drag-canvas', 'zoom-canvas', 'drag-node'],
            },
          });
    
          const main = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
              'https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/basement_prod/6cae02ab-4c29-44b2-b1fd-4005688febcb.json',
            );
            const remoteData = await response.json();
    
            const nodes = remoteData.nodes;
            const edges = remoteData.edges;
            nodes.forEach((node) => {
              if (!node.style) {
                node.style = {};
              }
              node.style.lineWidth = 1;
              node.style.stroke = '#666';
              node.style.fill = 'steelblue';
              switch (node.class) {
                case 'c0': {
                  node.type = 'circle';
                  node.size = 30;
                  break;
                }
                case 'c1': {
                  node.type = 'rect';
                  node.size = [35, 20];
                  break;
                }
                case 'c2': {
                  node.type = 'ellipse';
                  node.size = [35, 20];
                  break;
                }
              }
            });
            edges.forEach((edge) => {
              if (!edge.style) {
                edge.style = {};
              }
              edge.style.lineWidth = edge.weight;
              edge.style.opacity = 0.6;
              edge.style.stroke = 'grey';
            });
    
            graph.data(remoteData);
            graph.render();
    
            // Mouse enter a node
            graph.on('node:mouseenter', (e) => {
              const nodeItem = e.item; // Get the target item
              graph.setItemState(nodeItem, 'hover', true); // Set the state 'hover' of the item to be true
            });
    
            // Mouse leave a node
            graph.on('node:mouseleave', (e) => {
              const nodeItem = e.item; // Get the target item
              graph.setItemState(nodeItem, 'hover', false); // Set the state 'hover' of the item to be false
            });
    
            // Click a node
            graph.on('node:click', (e) => {
              // Swich the 'click' state of the node to be false
              const clickNodes = graph.findAllByState('node', 'click');
              clickNodes.forEach((cn) => {
                graph.setItemState(cn, 'click', false);
              });
              const nodeItem = e.item; // et the clicked item
              graph.setItemState(nodeItem, 'click', true); // Set the state 'click' of the item to be true
            });
    
            // Click an edge
            graph.on('edge:click', (e) => {
              // Swich the 'click' state of the edge to be false
              const clickEdges = graph.findAllByState('edge', 'click');
              clickEdges.forEach((ce) => {
                graph.setItemState(ce, 'click', false);
              });
              const edgeItem = e.item; // Get the clicked item
              graph.setItemState(edgeItem, 'click', true); // Set the state 'click' of the item to be true
            });
          };
          main();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use flexbox.

```css
#mountNode{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Tutorial Demo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="mountNode"></div>
        <script src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/antv/pkg/_antv.g6-3.7.1/dist/g6.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          const graph = new G6.Graph({
            container: 'mountNode',
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            // Default properties for all the nodes
            defaultNode: {
              labelCfg: {
                style: {
                  fill: '#fff',
                },
              },
            },
            // Default properties for all the edges
            defaultEdge: {
              labelCfg: {
                autoRotate: true,
              },
            },
            // The node styles in different states
            nodeStateStyles: {
              // The node style when the state 'hover' is true
              hover: {
                fill: 'lightsteelblue',
              },
              // The node style when the state 'click' is true
              click: {
                stroke: '#000',
                lineWidth: 3,
              },
            },
            // The edge styles in different states
            edgeStateStyles: {
              // The edge style when the state 'click' is true
              click: {
                stroke: 'steelblue',
              },
            },
            // Layout
            layout: {
              type: 'force',
              linkDistance: 100,
              preventOverlap: true,
              nodeStrength: -30,
              edgeStrength: 0.1,
            },
            // Built-in Behaviors
            modes: {
              default: ['drag-canvas', 'zoom-canvas', 'drag-node'],
            },
          });
    
          const main = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(
              'https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/basement_prod/6cae02ab-4c29-44b2-b1fd-4005688febcb.json',
            );
            const remoteData = await response.json();
    
            const nodes = remoteData.nodes;
            const edges = remoteData.edges;
            nodes.forEach((node) => {
              if (!node.style) {
                node.style = {};
              }
              node.style.lineWidth = 1;
              node.style.stroke = '#666';
              node.style.fill = 'steelblue';
              switch (node.class) {
                case 'c0': {
                  node.type = 'circle';
                  node.size = 30;
                  break;
                }
                case 'c1': {
                  node.type = 'rect';
                  node.size = [35, 20];
                  break;
                }
                case 'c2': {
                  node.type = 'ellipse';
                  node.size = [35, 20];
                  break;
                }
              }
            });
            edges.forEach((edge) => {
              if (!edge.style) {
                edge.style = {};
              }
              edge.style.lineWidth = edge.weight;
              edge.style.opacity = 0.6;
              edge.style.stroke = 'grey';
            });
    
            graph.data(remoteData);
            graph.render();
    
            // Mouse enter a node
            graph.on('node:mouseenter', (e) => {
              const nodeItem = e.item; // Get the target item
              graph.setItemState(nodeItem, 'hover', true); // Set the state 'hover' of the item to be true
            });
    
            // Mouse leave a node
            graph.on('node:mouseleave', (e) => {
              const nodeItem = e.item; // Get the target item
              graph.setItemState(nodeItem, 'hover', false); // Set the state 'hover' of the item to be false
            });
    
            // Click a node
            graph.on('node:click', (e) => {
              // Swich the 'click' state of the node to be false
              const clickNodes = graph.findAllByState('node', 'click');
              clickNodes.forEach((cn) => {
                graph.setItemState(cn, 'click', false);
              });
              const nodeItem = e.item; // et the clicked item
              graph.setItemState(nodeItem, 'click', true); // Set the state 'click' of the item to be true
            });
    
            // Click an edge
            graph.on('edge:click', (e) => {
              // Swich the 'click' state of the edge to be false
              const clickEdges = graph.findAllByState('edge', 'click');
              clickEdges.forEach((ce) => {
                graph.setItemState(ce, 'click', false);
              });
              const edgeItem = e.item; // Get the clicked item
              graph.setItemState(edgeItem, 'click', true); // Set the state 'click' of the item to be true
            });
          };
          main();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```